# Reg Exp not matching

Tags: regex, typescript

I have a regular expression that is not finding a match with text that is in my file

Reg Ex:

```
^[ \t]*#[ \t]+vtk[ \t]+DataFile[ \t]+Version[ \t]+([^\s]+)[ \t]*\n(.*)\n[ \t]*(ASCII|BINARY)[ \t]*\n[ \t]*DATASET[ \t]+([^ ]+)[ \t]*\n
```

File text:

```
# vtk DataFile Version 4.2
ASCII
DATASET
```

When I cut off the expression to the following it works:

```
 ^[ \t]*#[ \t]+vtk[ \t]+DataFile[ \t]+Version[ \t]+([^\s]+)[ \t]*\n(.*)\n[ \t]*
```

Why is the text not being matched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are matching `(.*)\n` too many and after DATASET there is no more data to match but in your pattern there is still `[ \t]+([^ ]+)[ \t]*\n` which are not optional.

Try it like this:

```
^[ \t]*#[ \t]+vtk[ \t]+DataFile[ \t]+Version[ \t]+([^\s]+)[ \t]*\n[ \t]*(ASCII|BINARY)[ \t]*\n[ \t]*DATASET
```

In parts, your pattern would look like:

- `^`
- `[ \t]*#`
- `[ \t]+vtk`
- `[ \t]+DataFile`
- `[ \t]+Version`
- `[ \t]+([^\s]+)` This group will match the 4.2
- `[ \t]*\n`
- `[ \t]*(ASCII|BINARY)`
- `[ \t]*\n`
- `[ \t]*DATASET`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fYAGwZ/1)

Comment: So I don't have access to the code to change the Reg Ex, I have to modify my file text. What would a string look like that would cause a match?

Comment: @afriedman111 You mean which string would match your initial pattern? For example this would match your original pattern https://regex101.com/r/Vomfgi/1